# Activiti Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot resolve identifier ''

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activiti

I am working on BPM project and using Activiti for the BPM configuration.

While executing the process I am facing one issue, where one of the property which is I am passing from one of the task expecting to meet to other task wont work.

This is the error I am facing:

> Activiti Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot resolve
> identifier ''

I data is passes from User Task to Service Task.

[image]

I am expecting that the based on the property the "Exclusive Gateway" should work.
The criteria I mentioned like:

[image]

The property which I mentioned in the "Condition" is not found while the process execution.(The Name right now, first part is dark out).

Any idea what issue it is or how can I get the property?

Thanks,
Atul

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and know how to use pass the property which the process expects and exclusive gateway.

We need to set the property at the time of task creation in the "Map"(variable map). So the process can get it wherever it looking for.
The property I set in the code where I created process.

[image]

There might be another way also but this way I fixed the issue which I faced.

Thanks,
Atul

Answer (score 0):

I would expect, when the variable is set on the user task form, it should be available later in the process.

try to use process debugger (available for flowable I am not sure about activiti)

Comment: yes might be ... I need to check that